# Unstable in listen special port Data Sms Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a application which receive Data sms from Telecom. In my code, I registerd dynamic Broadcastreceiver within a Activity. It work fine, but sometime I lost a few sms message and I don't know why. This is my code

```
 IntentFilter mFilter = new IntentFilter(
        "android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED");
 mFilter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);
 mFilter.addDataAuthority("localhost", "my port");
 mFilter.addDataScheme("sms");
 if (smsReceiver == null)
     smsReceiver = new SmsReceiverBroadcast(); 
 context.registerReceiver(smsReceiver, intentFilter);
```

after register BroadCast to activity I wait 60s

```
long time = 0;
int delay = 200;
while (!Variable.getMessage && !finish
        && !Util.isTimeout(time, Timer)) {
    Util.sleep(delay);
    time += delay;
}
```

And my BroadCastReceiver:

```
 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";
    if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("pdus")) {

    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    if (pdus != null) {
        String pduString = toHexString((byte[]) pdus[0]);

        LogParams.pdu = (byte[]) pdus[0];
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

        if (msgs[i].getMessageBody() != null) {
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            Variable.isReadPdu = true;          

        } else {
            PduParser pduparser = new PduParser();
            Pdu pdu = pduparser.parsePdu(pduString);
            str += pdu.getDecodedText();
            Variable.isReadPdu = true;             

        }
```

What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: define "lost a few sms" ? (you probably want to register your BR in the manifest to receive all sms)

Comment: I mean I lost about 100 messages per 1000 measssges. Oh absolutely no, I don't need resister BR in the manifest because i register dynamic within a activity.

Comment: define "lost". How do you know they are "lost" ?

Comment: yes I had a system that sent data message from Telecom to Android Client and it sent successfully but sometime Android Client didn't receive. It's unstable.

Comment: and, did the stock android messages app receive them ?

Comment: yes, but i think it's not effect to receive messages.